# A reasonable way to add attributes to an xml root element in C#

Tags: c#, xml

The function "WriteStartElement" does not return anything.  I find this a little bizzare.
So up until now I have been doing it like this.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(m_targetFilePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("client");
xmlWriter.Close();
xmlDoc.Load(m_targetFilePath);
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
```

Saving the doc, then reloading it to get hold of the start element so i can write attributes to it.  Does anybody know the correct way of doing this because I'm pretty sure what I'm doing isn't right.

I tried to use xmlWriter.AppendChild() but it doesnt seem to write out anything. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using 3.5 or higher, [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) would make you fall in love.

Comment: only just moved onto 3.5 - i think im about to convert my class

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
// add the root node    
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("client");
// add the attribute to root node
xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute("foo");

// add the value of the attribute
xmlWriter.WriteValue("attribute value...");

// close the attribute to root node
xmlWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
// close the root node
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using `XmlSerializer`?  Create a class to hold all your data, create an instance of your class and then use XmlSerializer to write it out to an XML file.